# Communicating with relay in Python

Tags: python-2.7, pyserial

I have a simple program that takes in two inputs and outputs true and false depending on the fact if they're equal or not.

The first input is taken only once and then i output a true or false after comparing the 2nd input with the first one. I have an infinite while loop for this. The program is something like this:

```
n = input()
while true:
    n2 = input()
    if n==n2:
        print true
    else:
        print false
```

So the issue is this:

Is there a way i can JUST use python with pySerial to turn a relay on and off?

I want the relay to keep on going as long as n2 == n but i want it to stop whenever they're not equal.

Also, can someone point me in the right direction with which port will it be and which bridge i'm supposed to use. I'm absolutely clueless about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the relay. The easiest approach would be to use a cheap Arduino-clone ([Adafruit Trinket](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1501)) or Raspberry Pie with an relay-board which is Arduino/Raspberry Pie 'compatible'. Just look one up on eBay or Amazon. You could then send the Arduino via pyserial/usb a signal to set the relay. This is pretty basic stuff and you will find a lot of tutorials on this matter. Without an external device which gives you GPIO ports and just your PC via a serial port? If you don't know what you are doing i would not touch that stuff because you could kill your mainboard. And since you are asking... ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can wire a solid-state relay to one of the serial port's handshaking outputs (EG RTS) and then control the relay by opening and closing the serial port. or by using pyserial to command the RTS pin high and low.

An electromechanical relay can be used instead but the serial port outputs are not strong enough to drive one directly, so a transistor and a power supply would also be required.